# I try to update to SQL but it show this error " object reference is not set instance of an object "

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim CON As SqlConnection

    CON = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PantienDatabase;Integrated Security=True")
    CON.Open()
    Try
        'cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Patient_Detail SET (Name ='" & TextBoxName.Text & "',Age = '" & TextBoxAge.Text & "',Sex = '" & TextBoxSex.Text & "',Address = '" & TextBoxAddress.Text & "',Check_In = '" & TextBoxCHiN.Text & "',Check_In_Illness = '" & TextBoxCHinL.Text & "',Sevice = '" & TextBoxService.Text & "',Check_out_Illness = '" & TextBoxCHoutL.Text & "',Check_out = '" & TextBoxCHout.Text & "',Transfer = '" & TextBoxTransfer.Text & "',Patient_result = '" & ComboBoxPtr.Text & "') WHERE ID = '" & TextBoxid.Text & "' "
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Patient_Detail SET (Name = @Name, Age = @Age, Sex = @Sex, Address = @Address, Check_In = @Check_In, Check_In_Illness =@Check_in_illness, Sevice =@Service, Check_out_Illness =@Check_out_Illness, Check_out = @Check_out ,Transfer = @Transfer, Patient_result = @Pantient_result WHERE ID = @ID "

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBoxid.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBoxName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", TextBoxAge.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", TextBoxSex.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBoxAddress.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check_In", TextBoxCHiN.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check_in_illness", TextBoxCHinL.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", TextBoxService.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check_out_Illness", TextBoxCHoutL.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check_out", TextBoxCHout.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer", TextBoxTransfer.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pantient_result", ComboBoxPtr.Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    CON.Close()
```

Comment: On what *line* do you get the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't declare `cmd` anywhere.  At least, not in that code block.  Thus, `cmd` is not set as an instance of anything.

Add this under your declaration of `CON`:

`Dim cmd as SqlCommand`

The set it to a new instance and set CON as the connection at the top of your `TRY` block:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = CON
```

Comment: i did what you said but it show an other error "Incorrect syntax near '(" at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: The SQL in the uncommented CommandText line is not good.  It has no closing `)`.

Comment: But your original problem is now gone.

Comment: If you mean the same error as in the Incorrect Syntax error then it should be asked as a new question since it's a different issue than your original post.